# Email Notification on receiving empty file

Tags: biztalk

We currently have an pipeline in the receive port to decrypt the file and send the file in to the Send port. We are not processing anything with in the file. Not an new issue came up, sometimes the file that comes to us is empty and biztalk when it tries to decrypt it and send to destination errors out. Is there any way I can send an email notification if the file is empty. Can I don do it in admin console without developing any custom pipeline component.

Comment: Is the file really empty?  As in 0 bytes?  The native File Adapter does not process 0 byte files so it would even be sent for decryption.

Comment: @Johns-305 Yeah you are right it errors out when it tries to decrypt. How can I handle this issue

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'decrypt'?  What Pipeline Component is involved.  Is it a custom Component?

Comment: @Johns Decode-Component-PGP Pipeline Component [BAJ]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch and send errors in Receive Ports, You have to create and configure a SMTP Send Port and set the Filter to ErrorReport.FailureCode exists and also add ErrorReport.ReceivePortName with name of your ReceivePort. With these filter the Send Port will suscribe and get the errors in the Receive Port.

But if you are using the native File Adapter, when an empty file arrives to the Receive Location, the adapter discard this file and no error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a PGP component, I'm going to presume it's a custom component based on one of the samples out there.

In that case, the correct way to handle this case is to modify the component to check the length of the incoming stream before attempting to decrypt.

If the steam is empty, 0 bytes, simply skip the actual decode.  You can then set a Context Property indicating an empty message which you can use to generate any alert later.

Now, make 200% sure you really need to send an email.  If empty files are a normal condition (you can verify with the sender) then generating a email is creating a superfluous alert which everyone will just ignore.

Answer (score -1):

you can custom the code and send an email via an helper in case of empty file. have a look on this blog:
http://ninocrudele.com/biztalk-and-zero-byte-file